# 2005 Chrysler 300c won't start, possibly connected with theft alarm system

Tags: no-crank-no-start, theft-prevention, chrysler-300c

My 2005 Chrysler 300c won't start. I bought the car used and it came with two keys. One of the keys has the chip in it, and the other one doesn't (just the key, without any electronics). Two days ago, my dad tried starting the car with the key without the chip. The car started but the alarm went off and the car shut off after a few seconds. Ever since then, I am unable to start the car with either key. I can hear the starter but there is no ignition. What is going on?

I've tried disconnecting the battery and reconnecting after a few minutes but without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using an non-programmed key to start the vehicle, it has triggered the anti-theft system.

According to the [Owner's Manual](http://www.chrysler.com/carryover/download/pdf/manuals/2005_LX_Chrysler_300C_SRT8.pdf);

> **To disarm the system:** Press the UNLOCK button on the keyless entry transmitter. Also, using a valid sentry key and moving the ignition
>   switch to the ON/START position will disarm the system.

If none of this works, you will have to have it towed to a dealership to have it reset.